"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND" error when using TypeScript project references
I'm trying to implement TypeScript's project references to be able import code from a common package between my application's services.
This is how the tsconfig.json of the shared package (database_models) is setup:
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node-lts/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declarationDir": "./types",
    "strict": true,
    "composite": true
  }
}


And the main package's tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node-lts/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../../lib/database_models"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declarationDir": "./types",
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@database_models/*": ["../../lib/database_models/src/*"]
    }
  }
}

The import:
import UsersModel from "@database_models/UsersModel.js";

Throws this error:
node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:854
  throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(packageName, fileURLToPath(base), null);
        ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@database_models/UsersModel.js' imported from C:\Users\jpedr\Documents\Workshop\Work\twitter-engage-bot\apps\api\dist\managers\DatabaseManager.js
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:854:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:927:18)        
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)      
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)  
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v20.15.0

I'm building the main package's files using tsc --build.
Here's what I've double-checked:

The paths value in the main package's tsconfig.json is pointing to the correct path.
Made sure to re-build the common package's files after setting composite: true in its tsconfig.json


I'm running into the same problem, albeit with relative paths ("../../lib/database_models"). I think we might need to use a bundler like Webpack.

Have you run npm install after modifying your tsconfig.json file?

You are facing a runtime issue here. Node is not able to resolve the import. But both references and compilerOptions.paths only have an impact on TypeScript resolves imports, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#paths-does-not-affect-emit. I suggest that you also post the package.json file(s) and the relevant rest of your project structure here. Otherwise, it's a lot of work to answer you question.

I hope this helps in the future
remove the .js extension in the import
from import UsersModel from "@database_models/UsersModel.js";
to import UsersModel from "@database_models/UsersModel";
I hope this helps.
If you have any questions feel free to reach out.
